# How can I split a PowerPoint file with multiple slides into multiple files of 1 slide each?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a file containing 50 slides. I need to create 50 different files each containing one of the slides. I guess the quickest way includes VBA, but I don't know how to get VBA to create a new file and then get back to the master.

Comment: loop over slides, addnew presentation at each iteration, copy slide to new presentation, save, close new presentation.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you meant "create 50 presentations", this will work. Create the destination folder before running the code:

```
Sub ExportSlides()
  For X = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    ActivePresentation.Slides(X).Export "c:\temp\slide" & X & ".pptx", "PPTX"
  Next X
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally found out this:

```
Sub ExportSlides()
    Dim oTempPres As Presentation
    Dim X As Long
    For X = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        sFileName = "C:\Raw\Slide__" & X & ".pptx"
        ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs sFileName

        Set oTempPres = Presentations.Open(sFileName, , , False)
        
        For Y = (X + 1) To oTempPres.Slides.Count
            oTempPres.Slides(X + 1).Delete
        Next
        
        For Y = 1 To X - 1
            oTempPres.Slides(1).Delete
        Next
        
        oTempPres.Save
        oTempPres.Close
        
    Next X
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

This code I had for a similar project should work to split out each PPT file to its PPT file and save it to the folder that contains the original PPT file.

Some caveats:

- it struggles with embedded graphs and sometimes backgrounds.
- this strips out all animations assigned to the slides or the template. If you want to keep animations or effects in, just strip out those lines of code
- I haven't taken the time to smooth out automating the UserForm showing up automatically, but you can easily run it by going to the Developer tab and running the OnPresentationOpen subroutine from the macros list.

Depending on your environment's security settings, you may also need to set the .pptm containing this VBA as a Trusted Document before it will work.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub OnPresentationOpen()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Public Sub ProcessPowerPoint(pptCalled)
    Dim pptMainPowerPt As Presentation
    Dim slideCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cleanSlide As Slide
    Dim newSaveName As String
    
    Set pptMainPowerPt = Presentations.Open(pptCalled)
    slideCount = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    
    ' Removes all animations from entire document first
    For Each cleanSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For i = cleanSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1
            'Remove Each Animation
            cleanSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(i).Delete
        Next i
    Next cleanSlide
    
    Debug.Print "The number of slides is "; slideCount
    Debug.Print "The name that is showing is "; pptCalled
    Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Name
    
    newSaveName = Left(pptCalled, InStr(pptCalled, ".") - 1)
    
    Debug.Print "Substring name is "; newSaveName
    
    For i = 1 To slideCount
        Dim newPresentation As Presentation
        Dim newName As String
        Dim currentSlide As Slide
         
        newName = newSaveName + "_Slide_" & i & ".pptx"
      
        Set currentSlide = pptMainPowerPt.Slides.Item(i)
        Set newPresentation = Application.Presentations.Add
        currentSlide.Copy
        newPresentation.Slides.Paste
        
       newPresentation.SaveAs (newName)
       newPresentation.Close
          
    Next
  
    pptMainPowerPt.Close
    
End Sub
```